# Android Opencv save mat as a picture without drawn rectangle

Tags: android, opencv

I want to save a Mat `mRgba` as a picture with `Imgcodecs.imwrite(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/final-image.jpg", mRgba);` and in general it saves more that I want to. I want to save image without rectangle `Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, new Point(touchedYD, touchedXL), new Point(touchedYU, touchedXR), Util.WHITE, 2);` that is drawn on screen before saving. How to achieve that?

Here is my code.

Fragment:

```
public class StageTwo extends Fragment implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2, OnSwitchFragmentFromStageTwo {
   

 @Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ((Stages) getActivity()).onSwitchFragmentFromStageTwo = this;

    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        
            // poziomo
            if (-event.getX() + camLayHeight + (xCorrection * 10) < (camLayHeight / 2)) {
                touchedXR = -event.getX() + camLayHeight + (xCorrection * 10);
                if (touchedXR < 0) touchedXR = 0;
            } else {
                touchedXL = -event.getX() + camLayHeight + (xCorrection * 10);
                if (touchedXL > camLayHeight) touchedXL = camLayHeight;
            }

            // pionowo
            if (event.getY() - (yCorrection * 10) < (camLayWidth / 2)) {
                touchedYU = event.getY() - (yCorrection * 10);
                if (touchedYU < 0) touchedYU = 0;
            } else {
                touchedYD = event.getY() - (yCorrection * 10);
                if (touchedYD > camLayWidth) touchedYD = camLayWidth;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    kamera = view.findViewById(R.id.java_surface_view);
    kamera.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    android.graphics.Point size = new android.graphics.Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int height = size.y;
    kamera.getLayoutParams().height = height / 2;
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    Core.transpose(mGray, mGray);
    Core.flip(mGray, mGray, -1);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame.rgba(), mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB, 1);

    if (gridPref.equals(getString(R.string.yes))) {
        Imgproc.line(mRgba, p1, p2, Util.BLUE);
        Imgproc.line(mRgba, p3, p4, Util.BLUE);
    }

    Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, new Point(touchedYD, touchedXL), new Point(touchedYU, touchedXR), Util.WHITE, 2);

    rozmiar_y = (int) ((touchedYU - touchedYD));
    rozmiar_x = (int) ((touchedXL - touchedXR));

    if (rozmiar_x > rozmiar_y)
        px_cm = (double) Math.round((rozmiar_x / Integer.parseInt(rozmiar)) * 100000) / 100000d;
    if (rozmiar_x < rozmiar_y)
        px_cm = (double) Math.round((rozmiar_y / Integer.parseInt(rozmiar)) * 100000) / 100000d;


    return mRgba;
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
    new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);

    camLayHeight = height;                  // mniejsza wartosc 480
    camLayWidth = width;

    touchedXL = camLayHeight / 2;
    touchedXR = camLayHeight / 2;
    touchedYD = camLayWidth / 2;
    touchedYU = camLayWidth / 2;
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
}

    @Override
    public double onSwitchFragmentFromFragmentTwo() {
        if (px_cm > 0.5) {
(...)
            Imgcodecs.imwrite(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/final-image.jpg", mRgba);
        }
        return px_cm;
    }
}
```

Activity

```
    OnSwitchFragmentFromStageTwo onSwitchFragmentFromStageTwo;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stages);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Stages.this);

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (!sp.getBoolean("correctionDone", false))
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new StageZero(this));
        else {
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new StageOne());
            bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_stage_one);
        }
        ft.commit();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        bottomNavigationView.setEnabled(false);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                (...)
                if (bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId() == R.id.navigation_stage_two) {
                    if (onSwitchFragmentFromStageTwo.onSwitchFragmentFromFragmentTwo() <= 0.5) {
                        (...)
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        (...)
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    (...)
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

I was trying to solve this problem by setting `touchedXL = 0; touchedXR = 0; touchedYD = 0; touchedYU = 0;` right before saving but it did not help, picture is still saved with this rectangle. If you need something more just ask. Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may **create a copy** of `mRgba` before drawing the rectangle.

- Add a new private class member `mRgbNoRect`:

  ```
  private Mat mRgbNoRect; //mRgba before drawing rectangle
  ```
- Initialize `mRgbNoRect` in `onCameraViewStarted`:

  ```
   public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
       mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
       mRgbNoRect = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
   }
  ```
- Create a copy of mRgba before drawing the rectangle in `onCameraFrame`:

  ```
   Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrameRgba, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

   mRgba.copyTo(mRgbNoRect); //Copy mRgba content to mRgbNoRect before drawing a rectangle 

   Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, new Point(20, 20), new Point(100, 100), new Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
  ```

  Note: It's just an example (not your original code).
- Add a "get" function `getRgbNoRect()`:

  ```
   public Mat getRgbNoRect() {
       return mRgbNoRect;
   }
  ```
- Get mRgbNoRect and save it (example):

  ```
   Mat rgbNoRect = sample.getRgbNoRect();   
   Imgcodecs.imwrite("rgbNoRect.png", rgbNoRect);
  ```

---

Here is a complete code sample (simple sample without a camera):

```
package myproject;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;

class Sample {
    
private Mat mRgba;
private Mat mRgbNoRect; //mRgba before drawing rectangle 

static { System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }


public Mat onCameraFrame() {
    //Create RGBA matrix filled with grin color - simulating inputFrame.rgba().
    Mat inputFrameRgba = Mat.zeros(200, 250, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    inputFrameRgba.setTo(new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255));

    Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrameRgba, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
    
    mRgba.copyTo(mRgbNoRect); //Copy mRgba content to mRgbNoRect before drawing a rectangle 

    Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, new Point(20, 20), new Point(100, 100), new Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);

    return mRgba;
}

public Mat getRgbNoRect() {
    return mRgbNoRect;
}

public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
    mRgbNoRect = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
}  
  
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sample sample = new Sample();
        
    sample.onCameraViewStarted(250, 200);
    
    Mat rgbWithRect = sample.onCameraFrame();
    Mat rgbNoRect = sample.getRgbNoRect();
    
    Imgcodecs.imwrite("rgbWithRect.png", rgbWithRect);
    Imgcodecs.imwrite("rgbNoRect.png", rgbNoRect);
}

}
```

---

Notes:

- The code sample is tested in Windows, and I am not sure if it can be executed in Android as is.
- The last time I programmed in JAVA was many years ago, so I hope I didn't do some rookie's mistakes.